# How to prevent inconsistent reads in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a problem with django and postgresql.

Suppose one process have been loaded some model.

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
#user.foo is '' right now
user.foo = 'bar'
```

And while this process doing that another doing something with this table.

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
#user.xyz is '' right now
user.xyz = 'xyz'
```

then first one saves and then the other.

In the end I would have a user models object with foo = '' and xyz = 'xyz', while I want foo to be equal to 'bar'.

I think it's called 'lost update' or something. I think that in isolation level 'serializable' it shouldn't be so.

Comment: Looks like you need to use SELECT FOR UPDATE. So that rows locks for both reads and write operations.

Comment: What is select for update?

Comment: Have a look on:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update

and: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE 

It is your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`Model.save` overwrite all fields with current objects attributes.

To overwrite only the desired one, you need to specify using `update_fields` (available since Django 1.5):

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
user.foo = 'bar'
user.save(update_fields=['foo'])

# ---

user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
user.xyz = 'xyz'
user.save(update_fields=['xyz'])
```

See [Specifying which fields to save - Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save).

BTW, if you don't reload `user` object in another process, you will still see `foo = '', xyz = 'xyz'`. Reload it to see updated field values.

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=user.pk)
```

Comment: This could indeed work if we knew process A was only touching foo and process B was only touching xyz.  Although this looks like a concurrency problem.  Process A should than wait for process B to release the lock on that one user table row.